# Moodle custom text editor button

Tags: moodle

I;m currently working on a plugin in moodle that allows for the importing of certain video's into moodle's page plugin. Is there a way for me to put my own button in the page editor? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at filters

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Filters

The filter will replace text with the original video

There are a few existing filters here

https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=7